# What is the difference between @types/material-ui and the official @mui/types package?

Tags: typescript, material-ui

npm packages: [@types/material-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/material-ui) and [@mui/types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/types)

I know the former is supported by the Definitely Typed community but why does it exist in the first place if an official types package exists? I've searched a lot and found nothing about the why.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out @types/material-ui is for the v0 version of [material-ui from 5 years ago](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui). It's long outdated and I doubt anyone uses it anymore. Starting from v1, MUI started shipping their own types.

You should not install `@mui/types` in any project. [The MUI package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/material) comes with it's own types already so need need a separate types package. You can tell based off the TS logo at the top of the npm page. And the code has a `index.d.ts` file inside it where it exports the types.